# SVG animacion se tilda en Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, html5, svg, snap.svg

Armé una animación SVG que simula dar la vuelta a una página del libro. Y en Mozilla anda de maravilla, el problema son los navegadores Chrome y Opera. ¿Alguien que me ayude a optimizar la animación para que funcione más fluido en Chrome?

Éste es el código ([también disponible en Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LONQaq)):

```js
/*!
 * classie - class helper functions
 * from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo
 * 
 * classie.has( elem, 'my-class' ) -> true/false
 * classie.add( elem, 'my-new-class' )
 * classie.remove( elem, 'my-unwanted-class' )
 * classie.toggle( elem, 'my-class' )
 */

/*jshint browser: true, strict: true, undef: true */
/*global define: false */

(function(window) {

  'use strict';

  // class helper functions from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo

  function classReg(className) {
    return new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + className + "(\\s+|$)");
  }

  // classList support for class management
  // altho to be fair, the api sucks because it won't accept multiple classes at once
  var hasClass, addClass, removeClass;

  if ('classList' in document.documentElement) {
    hasClass = function(elem, c) {
      return elem.classList.contains(c);
    };
    addClass = function(elem, c) {
      elem.classList.add(c);
    };
    removeClass = function(elem, c) {
      elem.classList.remove(c);
    };
  } else {
    hasClass = function(elem, c) {
      return classReg(c).test(elem.className);
    };
    addClass = function(elem, c) {
      if (!hasClass(elem, c)) {
        elem.className = elem.className + ' ' + c;
      }
    };
    removeClass = function(elem, c) {
      elem.className = elem.className.replace(classReg(c), ' ');
    };
  }

  function toggleClass(elem, c) {
    var fn = hasClass(elem, c) ? removeClass : addClass;
    fn(elem, c);
  }

  var classie = {
    // full names
    hasClass: hasClass,
    addClass: addClass,
    removeClass: removeClass,
    toggleClass: toggleClass,
    // short names
    has: hasClass,
    add: addClass,
    remove: removeClass,
    toggle: toggleClass
  };

  // transport
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // AMD
    define(classie);
  } else {
    // browser global
    window.classie = classie;
  }

})(window);


/**
 * svgLoader.js v1.0.0
 * http://www.codrops.com
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license.
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 * 
 * Copyright 2014, Codrops
 * http://www.codrops.com
 */
;
(function(window) {

  'use strict';

  function extend(a, b) {
    for (var key in b) {
      if (b.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        a[key] = b[key];
      }
    }
    return a;
  }

  function SVGLoader(el, options) {
    this.el = el;
    this.options = extend({}, this.options);
    extend(this.options, options);
    this._init();
  }

  SVGLoader.prototype.options = {
    speedIn: 500,
    easingIn: mina.linear
  }

  SVGLoader.prototype._init = function() {
    var s = Snap(this.el.querySelector('svg'));
    this.path = s.select('path');
    this.initialPath = this.path.attr('d');

    var openingStepsStr = this.el.getAttribute('data-opening');
    this.openingSteps = openingStepsStr ? openingStepsStr.split(';') : '';
    this.openingStepsTotal = openingStepsStr ? this.openingSteps.length : 0;
    if (this.openingStepsTotal === 0) return;

    // if data-closing is not defined then the path will animate to its original shape
    var closingStepsStr = this.el.getAttribute('data-closing') ? this.el.getAttribute('data-closing') : this.initialPath;
    this.closingSteps = closingStepsStr ? closingStepsStr.split(';') : '';
    this.closingStepsTotal = closingStepsStr ? this.closingSteps.length : 0;

    this.isAnimating = false;

    if (!this.options.speedOut) {
      this.options.speedOut = this.options.speedIn;
    }
    if (!this.options.easingOut) {
      this.options.easingOut = this.options.easingIn;
    }
  }

  SVGLoader.prototype.show = function() {
    if (this.isAnimating) return false;
    this.isAnimating = true;
    // animate svg
    var self = this,
      onEndAnimation = function() {
        classie.addClass(self.el, 'pageload-loading');
      };
    this._animateSVG('in', onEndAnimation);
    classie.add(this.el, 'show');
  }

  SVGLoader.prototype.hide = function() {
    var self = this;
    classie.removeClass(this.el, 'pageload-loading');
    this._animateSVG('out', function() {
      // reset path
      self.path.attr('d', self.initialPath);
      classie.removeClass(self.el, 'show');
      self.isAnimating = false;
    });
  }

  SVGLoader.prototype._animateSVG = function(dir, callback) {
    var self = this,
      pos = 0,
      steps = dir === 'out' ? this.closingSteps : this.openingSteps,
      stepsTotal = dir === 'out' ? this.closingStepsTotal : this.openingStepsTotal,
      speed = dir === 'out' ? self.options.speedOut : self.options.speedIn,
      easing = dir === 'out' ? self.options.easingOut : self.options.easingIn,
      nextStep = function(pos) {
        if (pos > stepsTotal - 1) {
          if (callback && typeof callback == 'function') {
            callback();
          }
          return;
        }
        self.path.animate({
          'path': steps[pos]
        }, speed, easing, function() {
          nextStep(pos);
        });
        pos++;
      };

    nextStep(pos);
  }

  // add to global namespace
  window.SVGLoader = SVGLoader;

})(window);

(function() {
  var pageWrap = document.getElementById('pagewrap'),
    pages = [].slice.call(pageWrap.querySelectorAll('div.container')),
    currentPage = 0,
    triggerLoading = [].slice.call(pageWrap.querySelectorAll('a.pageload-link')),
    loader = new SVGLoader(document.getElementById('loader'), {
      speedIn: 1000,
      easingIn: mina.easeinout
    });

  function init() {
    triggerLoading.forEach(function(trigger) {
      trigger.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        loader.show();
        // after some time hide loader
        setTimeout(function() {
          loader.hide();

          classie.removeClass(pages[currentPage], 'show');
          // update..
          currentPage = currentPage ? 0 : 1;
          classie.addClass(pages[currentPage], 'show');

        }, 2000);
      });
    });
  }

  init();
})();
```

```css
.container {
  display: none;
}

.container.show {
  display: block;
}

.pageload-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 134%;
  top: -112px;
  left: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  background-size: cover;
}

.pageload-overlay.show {
  visibility: visible;
}

.pageload-overlay svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.5.1/snap.svg-min.js"></script>

<div id="pagewrap" class="pagewrap">
  <div class="container show" id="page-1">
    <div class="column">
      <p><a class="pageload-link" href="#page-2">Show Page Loader</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /container -->

  <div class="container" id="page-2">
    <section>
      <p><a class="pageload-link" href="#page-1">Go back</a></p>
    </section>
  </div>
  <!-- /container -->

  <div id="loader" class="pageload-overlay" data-opening="M 0,0 c 0,0 63.5,-16.5 80,0 16.5,16.5 0,60 0,60 L 0,60 Z">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 80 60" preserveAspectRatio="none">
      <defs>
        <pattern id="img1" width="1" height="1">
          <image href="https://images4.alphacoders.com/888/thumb-1920-8.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"/>
        </pattern>
      </defs>
      <path d="M 0,0 c 0,0 -16.5,43.5 0,60 16.5,16.5 80,0 80,0 L 0,60 Z" fill="url(#img1)"/>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <!-- /pageload-overlay -->
</div>
<!-- /pagewrap -->
```

Comment: El snippet parece funcionar igual en Chrome 61 y Firefox 56.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro igual de mal o igual de bien? Porque yo cuando lo compilo con Visual Studio para Mozilla, me anda bien, pero la misma compilacion para Chrome y Opera, se tilda bastante.

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir unos gif de cómo lo ves en Mozilla comparado con Chrome y Opera? A mí se me ven casi igual, pero la verdad es que no sé exactamente qué es lo que debería ver

Comment: Basicamente en mozilla se abre fluido la hoja de madera. En Chrome se abre por partes, se tilda cada 30% mas o menos y por eso se ve cortada esa animacion.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "se tilda"? Todavía no termino de comprender qué significa :$

Comment: Que la animacion donde la hoja de mandera se desplega, se ve cortada -  el antonimo del fluido. No se si me explico

Comment: Así es como yo lo veo en [Chrome](https://i.imgur.com/AedDkKu.gif) y como lo veo en [Firefox](https://i.imgur.com/aoJu1QL.gif). La diferencia es mínima o ninguna (parece que uno termina un poco más arriba que el otro, pero poco más).